# Error with map environment variables in ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to export environmental variables in ansible where the variable is a map variable as follows.

Ex.

```
 Variable_123: 
   VAR23='
   global:
     string: abcd
   environment:
     local:
       version: 2.32
   '
```

This when set using `environment` function in ansible as below:

```
- name: Run tests
  environment: {{ Variable_123 }}
```

Gives error

```
mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 1):

[*environment*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-remote-environment-in-a-task) is a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
  environment:
    NVM_DIR: /var/local/nvm
    PATH: /var/local/nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}
```

In your case, you probably want to create such an environment dictionary in the variable *Variable_123* where the environment variable *VAR23* keeps the YAML dictionary as a string

```yaml
  Variable_123:
    VAR23: |
      global:
        string: abcd
      environment:
        local:
          version: 2.32
```

You can use this environment

```yaml
    - command: echo $VAR23
      environment: "{{ Variable_123 }}"
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
  out.stdout: |-
    global:
      string: abcd
    environment:
      local:
        version: 2.32
```

You can convert the string to the dictionary

```yaml
  VAR23: "{{ out.stdout|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  VAR23:
    environment:
      local:
        version: 2.32
    global:
      string: abcd
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    Variable_123:
      VAR23: |
        global:
          string: abcd
        environment:
          local:
            version: 2.32

    VAR23: "{{ out.stdout|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - command: echo $VAR23
      environment: "{{ Variable_123 }}"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - debug:
        var: VAR23
    - debug:
        var: VAR23.environment.local.version
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: |-
    global:
      string: abcd
    environment:
      local:
        version: 2.32

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  VAR23:
    environment:
      local:
        version: 2.32
    global:
      string: abcd

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  VAR23.environment.local.version: '2.32'

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```